# $result not usable after mysql_fetch_assoc($result), why

Tags: php, mysql, database

i get data from sql then run 
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
...
}

then i try to do the same thing but its giving nothing like result is empty does using mysql_fetch_assoc() clears $request variable?

Answer (score 2):

The function keeps a counter, so of course you can't keep using it when it's gotten to the end. Is there a particular reason for looping through it twice? Anyways:

```
mysql_data_seek($request, 0);
```

Is what you need before the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

You've hit the end of $result resurce using `while` loop. To solve this, rewind your pointer back to 0 position when you want to use your resource again... look at [mysql_data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) function for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` itself doesn't know when you are and are not calling it in a while loop. It doesn't magically reset to the start of the resultset when you use it in a separate loop.

Reset it to the start of the resultset with `mysql_data_seek` once you've reached the end and want to go back to the beginning... or, ideally, remove your need to iterate the results twice.